# There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:28069/Administration/AuthenticationService.svc that could accept the message

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-binding

Is there anyone to help with problem, when uploaded the project to bitbucket.org I started geting this message, before uploading it was working without this error. even i have the copy of the project works on computer,

when i upload the project to bitbucket.org there is some assembly dlls that should be reinstalled, as I install System.Net.Http.Formatting version 5.2.3.0. before it was 4.0.0.0 version not restored.

Now I am geting the message.

**Message**
"There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:28069/Administration/AuthenticationService.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details."

**source**
"mscorlib"

**InnerException**
{"Unable to connect to the remote server"}

Answer (score 1):

The answer for this error was just updating the api wcf 's service references. I just updated all the service references of wcf services. and worked fine.

Second solution is that to start the project in which wcf services are implemented there.